# What voltages would you expect to see in this push - pull amplifier

Tags: amplifier, audio, push-pull

I am repairing a friends amplifier, and its 40 odd years since I played around with electronics like this, so I'm very rusty!  I've replaced all the transistors etc. (more than once!) and before I start injecting an input signal, I want to check I am seeing the right voltages - but what are they? (I've long since forgotten how these amps actually work.  Supply voltage is +43 V and -43 V.  At the moment I'm seeing +0.695 V on the base of Q109, and -0.992 V on the base of Q110. Something in the dim and distant past is telling me these voltages should be equal and opposite? But really, I just can't remember anymore.

In particular what is the function of RV107?  I know the o/p stage amplifies current, but this is the only adjustment I have and I wanted to know where it should be set before proceeding to blowing the wretched thing up again!  Do I need to adjust this to get a particular voltage somewhere, or does it regulate current somehow?  (I'm old, please don't judge me!)

Any pointers to help me not blow this thing up again would be very welcome.

[image]

[image: Full circuit of the amplifier]

Comment: Have you thought about simulating the circuit? BTW, where did the schematic come from?

Comment: I tried to simulate it but the simulator I was using didnt have all the components so I had to use ones which were 'close enough'. The voltages were different in the simulator than in reality.  Can you recommend a good simulator (that's free) and has a good library of components?

Comment: Oh, and the circuit is from a Bass amplifier (Warwick Take12)  I've left out the pre-amp etc as its irrelevant. Happy to post it in full if you like?

Comment: Micro cap is what I use and many others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to the problem turned out to be simple.  Don't buy cheap electronic components from China. They are mostly fake.  Buy from a reputable component supplier like RS or Farnell.

As soon as I bought quality components the circuit sprang into life and now works perfectly.

Comment: Congratulations. Good to hear you sorted it out after a few months. Just a reminder: You can accept your own answer (this one) so the question does not remain open.

Answer (score 2):

RV107 adjusts the voltage bias from base to base of the output transistors for class AB operation. Adjust while watching a sine wave at the output for no crossover distortion.

The output transistors are complementary Darlington types so VBE will be higher. 0.695 seems low so I suspect in cut off. -0.995 seems a little low as well but may be conducting a bit.

Once adjusted for class AB operation the symmetry may return.

I suspect that the voltage should be 1.2 V plus-minus, but use crossover distortion as a guide.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I'm not going mad then.  That is exactly what I did the first time I replaced all the transistors, as thats what I guessed the pot was for.  Mid range, I was getting crosover distrotion.  I had to adjust the pot way over to one side (please dont ask me which way, a lot has happened since then) to get rid of the cross over.

Comment: Whopee I thought! Crossover gone, but pot pretty much fully over to one side.  Until pop - the OP transistors blew. (Fuses blew too, but didn't protect me.)  So I tried again, and guess what - same thing happened.   I'm at a point now where I've replaced all the transistors, pretty much all the diodes, C106, 108 and 109, RT101, R110 and R105.  (there may have been a few other resistors I changed too.).  I've gone through about 8 pairs of o/p transistors and I'm on the vergre of giving up. Hence my cry for help.

Comment: But if that is what the pot is for, and If I know VBE on the o/p transistors should be around 1.2v thats a great help at least.

Comment: @Simon. The pot should not be all one way. With no signal input, the current through the output transistors should be single digit milli-amps. You still have a problem elsewhere. 1.2V may be too high.

Comment: Thank you all for the help with this. I believe it is fixed.  I found that the pot RV107 had a cracked track. So intermittently it was going open circuit. And of course when adjusting it and traversing the crack, well, you get the picture.  I replaced the pot and suddenly no cross over distortion when it is sitting mid range.  I have one final question though ....

Comment: Am I right in thinking that C105 is the wrong way round on the circuit diagram?  shouldn't the +ve be on the input side, not on the amp side?  I ask because although the amp is working it seems to be a little down on volume, and I'm wondering if I put that capacitor in the wrong way round when I replaced it (I followed the circuit diagram)

Comment: I can’t see where input side of C105 is connected. Measure the dc voltage across it. The positive terminal should be connected to the more positive voltage.

Comment: It might be best to replace C105 with a non-polarized ceramic multilayer, or maybe a film type. All the electrolytics in a 40 year old amp are suspect, and should be tested or simply replaced.

Comment: @PStechPaul: ceramics have a voltage dependency except C0G/NP0 types that will distort an audio signal. A film capacitor is better if going non-polarized.

Comment: @PStechPaul Yes, I did replace it for exactly that reason, along with all the other electrolytics. I'm annoyed at myself for not checking which way round the original was before I took it out.    However I have checked the voltage across the C105 and on the amp side it is 0v.  On the pre-amp side it is 0.04v.  So I'm wondering if I am worrying over nothing?

Comment: I suppose the question is, will that affect the input level of the incoming signal?  I suspect not tbh.

Comment: @Simon: An electrolytic is not a good choice. They can get away with it if the ac amplituce of the signal is low. I would replace it with a film type of capacitor. Stay awa from ceramics for this.

Comment: Well, I give up. (That cap is the least of my worries).  I trusted the circuit diagram, and plugged the bass in, and switched it on. All seemed ok until I turned up the volume and *boom* - a spectacular blow up with sparks and everything.  R109 completely fried.  Looks like RV107 has melted. I'd changed pretty much every component in that circuit, and it still didn't work.  I remember now why I found electronics so frustrating.